# Pin to the superview constraint in Xcode 7 is not available anymore?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

In Xcode 7 there is no longer an option to "pin to superview," before you could go to `Editor>Pin>Leading Space To Superview` now the menu looks like the option below. On the pin menu at the bottom there are still options to add pin constraints to the nearest neighbor but I can not find any way to pin to the superview. How do you now go about pining to the superview?

[image]

Comment: You can check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33173317/468724

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pin Horizontal Spacing in Xcode 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812367/pin-horizontal-spacing-in-xcode-7)