# Xcode 7 - Vertical Spacing Constraint

Tags: ios, xcode7

Okay I'm probably missing something. This was a fairly simple operation in Xcode 6, but I can't seem to find the same option in Xcode 7.

Consider this layout:

[image]

I want a vertical spacing constraint between Label 1 and Label 3. In Xcode 6, I can just multi select Label 1 and Label 3, go to Editor -> Pin -> Vertical Spacing. That Pin option, however, is no longer in Xcode 7. I can set vertical spacing between nearest elements, but not elements of my choice.

Does anyone know if that Vertical Spacing option was just re-arranged to another tab? Or if it's gone?

(I can probably do this programmatically, but I just want to know if there's a way to do it via Storyboard)

Comment: I have the same question. I'm going through the Plymouth University iOS Development in Swift course and very new to Xcode. I'm using 7.2.1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can ctrl drag the 3rd label to the first label and release ctrl and select vertical spacing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I kept looking and found the following link where it suggests adding a constraint to do the vertical spacing.

[Pin Horizontal Spacing Between Two UIImage Views in Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812367/pin-horizontal-spacing-between-two-uiimage-views-in-xcode-7)

Note: I added the constraint. When I attempted to do another update after Ctrl clicking I saw the option **Vertical Spacing** selected. Strange since the Vertical Spacing option does not appear the first time.